# Ocultar botones Según el rol Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, model-view-controller

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de marcación de entrada y salida de una empresa en laravel y tengo un inconveniente según el rol:

- Administrador
- Supervisor

-Si es Administrador que pueda editar y eliminar su propia marcacion y las de los demás empleados

-Si es Supervisor que no pueda editar y eliminar su propia marcacion (que se oculten los botones para su marcacion) pero si pueda editar la de los demás empleados (que se muestren los botones para las demas marcacion)

Manejos los roles con el campo groupId donde 1=Administrador y 3=Supervisor

Esta es la pantalla donde se visualizan las marcaciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo de la vista

```
@if(Auth::user()->groupId == 1)
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                                onclick="modalForm('{{ url('/editClock/'.$r['id']) }}', 'Editar marcación');"
                                title="Editar"><img src="img/icons/edit.png"/></button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"
                                onclick="modalForm('{{ url('/showClockActivity/'.$r['id']) }}', 'Ver Actividades', true);"
                                title="Actividades"><img src="img/icons/doc.png"/></button>
                    @else
                        <button type="button" style="display: none" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                                onclick="modalForm('{{ url('/editClock/'.$r['id']) }}', 'Editar marcación');"
                                title="Editar"><img src="img/icons/edit.png"/></button>
                        <button type="button" style="display: none" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"
                                onclick="modalForm('{{ url('/showClockActivity/'.$r['id']) }}', 'Ver Actividades', true);"
                                title="Actividades"><img src="img/icons/doc.png"/></button>
                    @endif
```

Pero con este codigo me oculta los botones para todos los resultados

Este es la funcion en el controlador que ejecuta la consulta para mostrar los resultados en la vista

```
 public function index(Request $request)
{
    $from = Carbon::today();//->subDays(10);
    $to = Carbon::today();
    $rmsg = '';
    $title = 'Reporte de marcación';

    $projects = ['' => 'Seleccione cliente'];

    $clock = clock::Areas()->orderBy('tm_clock.id', 'desc');

    if($request->input('filter_employee')){
        $clock = $clock->where('tm_clock.employeeId', '=', $request->input('filter_employee'));
        $emp = employee::find($request->input('filter_employee'));

        $rmsg .= 'Colaborador: '.$emp->Name.' '.$emp->LastName;
    }
return view('TaskManager.clock.index')->with(['clock' => $clock, 'employees' => $employees, 'areas' => $areas, 'clients' => $clients, 'projects' => $projects, 'request' => $request]);
```

Como valido si el usuario es supervisor y se llama TestUser no se muestren los botones para eliminar o editar el registro donde aparece su nombre pero si se muestre para eliminar o editar los demás registros

Comment: Lo que hago es un ajax al iniciar la app y obtengo el rango o tipo de usuario y según la respuesta ejecuto una función que me ocultara las funciones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que quieres hacer es sencillo.

Primero declara una función acciones:

```
<?php

 public function acciones($rol){
   return $rol ? 'codigohtml1' : 'codigohtml2';
 }

?>
```

Y en la vista pones:

```
<td> {!! acciones(auth()->rol) !!} </td>
<td> {!! acciones(auth()->rol) !!} </td>
```

...

```
<td> {!! acciones(auth()->rol) !!} </td>
<td> {!! acciones(auth()->rol) !!} </td>
<td> {!! acciones(auth()->rol) !!} </td>
```

...etc

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar las reglas en `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider` de la siguiente forma:

```
/**
 * Register any authentication / authorization services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Gate::define('editar', function ($user, $clock) {
        return $user->groupId == 1 || $post->employeeId = $user->id;
    });
}
```

y en tu vista lo usas asi:

```
@can('editar', $clock)
    <button>Tus botones</button>
@endcan
```

Puedes encontrar mas información aquí: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization